# Bring a singleInstance Activity Back Using a Notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, launchmode

I have a normal activity, let's call it A, and it's the first activity presented to the user when opening the app. Activity A has a button that launches an activity, let's call it B, with `launchMode` set to `singleInstance` in the manifest. Activity B does some processing.

Users can press the home button and open the app again, which will present them with the starting activity, aka activity A. If users click on the button again (in activity A), they will be presented with activity B. In the case, activity B will not be restarted, i.e., `onCreate` will not be called, since it is `singleInstance`, which is what I want.

I want to make it easier for the users to **come back** to activity B once it started if they pressed the home button. So, I created an ongoing notification that lets the users bring activity B back. The ongoing notification will be canceled once activity B is finished.

Now to the problem, clicking the ongoing notification recreates activity B again, i.e., the `onCreate` is being called again. I don't know why the behavior here is not the same as clicking on the button on activity A. Here is how I created the notification:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(mContext, CallActivity.class);

PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        mContext, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_call_white_18)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working and how can I get it to work the way I described?

**EDIT**

Here is a snippet of my manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.mnm.caller.IMApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name="com.mnm.caller.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.mnm.caller.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.mnm.caller.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.mnm.caller.activities.CallActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitleBar" />


    <service
        android:name="com.mnm.caller.services.IMFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: In general this approach is wrong. The special launch modes `singleTask` and `singleInstance` should only be used in very special situations. Please post your manifest and I can suggest an alternative.

Comment: @DavidWasser I updated my question with the manifest, could you please have a look at it.

Comment: Your single instance `Activity` is not actually being launched in a separate task because you haven't specified `taskAffinity` in the manifest. This means that Android is ignoring the special launch mode and treating this as a normal `Activity`.

If you were actually launching 2 separate tasks, then you would see 2 separate entries in the "list of recent tasks", both of which would have the same name and icon. This would confuse your users. These are just some of the reasons why you should not use the special launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask`. They have lots of side-effects.

Comment: If the user puts the app in the background with `Activity` B on top, why shouldn't `Activity` B be shown when the user launches the app again? Please explain your navigation requirements and maybe we can help you with the correct solution.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for your reply. I'm actually developing a calling app. Activity A is the home screen, while B is the calling activity. I want to let the users navigate back to the home screen during a call, so I intentionally and knowingly chose to create two instances of the app in recent apps (you can see the exact behavior in the default phone app on Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you wrote:

> I'm actually developing a calling app. Activity A is the home screen,
>   while B is the calling activity. I want to let the users navigate back
>   to the home screen during a call, so I intentionally and knowingly
>   chose to create two instances of the app in recent apps (you can see
>   the exact behavior in the default phone app on Android)

If this is the case, you probably do want to have 2 separate tasks that you can switch between. To do this, you need to use `taskAffinity`. Your `CallActivity` should have launch mode of `singleTask` or `singleInstance` and you should set `android:taskAffinity="call"` or something like that. In order not to confuse your users, you should also provide a different `android:label` and a different `android:icon` for `CallActivity` so that when this task appears in the list of recent tasks it looks different than the rest of your app. Make sure that when you launch `CallActivity` you also set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. You should also set this flag when you build the `Notification`.

Comment: I tried your solution, this is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the `Intent` instance (in your case `notifyIntent`) before creating the `PendingIntent` object.

In other words:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(mContext, CallActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        mContext, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_call_white_18)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```